# How to style image which is overlaping

Tags: css, reactjs

I am developing a product information page where a user clicks on the product he should get the product image, description and below that recommended products

The problem is when the user clicks the products, the image of the products get over recommended products and changes the whole style and for some products, it is working perfectly

This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFCJ8.png) that it should look like which works perfectly for some products

This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V50Hq.png) of some products where they are overlapping and changing the UI

Actually, in the product information, 3 components are embedded together and displaying.

I tried to bring down the recommended products below but it affects the home page recommended products.

Is there any solution for this

`margin-top: 0.005rem;` I tried this by increasing it to 40 but it affects the main home page styling. I don't want this and in this product image I tried to reduce the height and width and width of the image quality goes off and for some products like mobile it doesn't look good

This is the carousel border CSS code

```
export const CarouselBorder = styled(Heading)`
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
  margin-top: 0.005rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
`
```

This is the image css code:

```
    export const ImageGrid = styled.div`
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 78%;`
```

Comment: pls share html css code

Comment: @Ranjithv can check the updated question with code added to it

Comment: Just give your description paragraph a fitting `min-height`

Comment: can you share your website URL for me.. i will check and let you know.. i think there is add any min height for parent div

Comment: Do you have float styling (float:left for example) in containers above? You need a div with "clear:both;" styling to reset float styling.

Comment: @Ranjithv the website is not live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clear` property is used to specify which side of floating elements are not allowed to float. It sets or returns the position of the element in relation to floating objects. If the element can fit horizontally in the space next to another element which is floated.

Syntax:

```
clear: none|left|right|both|initial;
```